# Code teaching and animation videos - Software recommendation

Tags: software-recommendation, animation

I want to make code teaching video animations. Something similar to this

https://youtu.be/UF9Iqmg94tk?t=195

I want to know what software/app should I use for making professional looking animation video. Don't mind buying a subscription.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the perfecr place to ask. The question really hinges on wether or not you have done animation previously or not. In my experience, anecdotal as it is (i only have about 500 datapoints), people with no natural curiosity towards animation rarely make it through their first project. Simply because they underestimate the workload by one or two orders of magnitude. Also you need to choose your application to suit your worldview. You probably want to be using something like mathematica rather than blender or afterefects for example.

Comment: Anyway animation isnt a skill you can usually pick up in a month or two.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's lots of animation software out there which would be capable of 2D animations like the example, some free, some not. e.g., After Effects, Blender (free), Adobe Animate, Synfig Studio (free). Most are somewhat complex tools though, and have a steep learning curve.  Money isn't the only consideration here, the time spent learning the software could be quite considerable.

Comment: If it's any help to you, there is a Blender Stack Exchange, and a Video Production Stack Exchange where you can perhaps get some more specific advice perhaps. Also there's a Software Recs Stack Exchange.